# How do you add an Objects keys to a prototype?

Tags: javascript

How can you add all of an objects key / values to a prototype.

For example if I had the object

```
var serverResponse = {
    foo: 'bar'
    id: 123
    name: 'Rick Sanchez'
}
```

And I wanted to add each key to the prototype of a Person. I could manually do it for each key like this.

```
function Person(serverResponse) {
    this.foo = serverResponse.foo;
    this.id = serverResponse.id;
    this.name = serverResponse.name;
}
```

But I'm sure there is a better way to do this....

Comment: You might think so, but no, I don't think there is. It might be easier to just say `this.serverResponse = serverResponse` and then just refer to things like `this.serverResponse.id` later in your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you're not wanting to add to the prototype, but to copy all properties over. This can be done in modern browsers with `Object.assign` (which can be introduced with a polyfill for ancient browsers):

```
function Person(serverResponse) {
  Object.assign(this, serverResponse);
}
```

...of course you have to trust that `serverResponse` doesn't have data you don't want in your object. If you do indeed want to assign to the prototype, you can use `Object.assign` on the prototype as well:

```
Object.assign(Person.prototype, serverResponse);
```

Comment: This becomes incredibly brittle, and hard to debug when you add a new property on `serverResponse` that happens to be the same name as a method on the prototype of Person.

Comment: I realized that while this was exactly what I was looking for, in the end it is much better to assign the response to it's own property. In my case I set this.DTO to server response and then I can still add whatever properties I'd like without having to worry about name collision.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think you want to add it to the prototype of `Person`, because that makes it available on every instance of `Person` (and it seems like `serverResponse` contains variables specific to a certain instance, not all instances, of a `Person` - this is most likely just a problem with the terminology of your question title).

That being said, I do this all the time - I pass a generic JS object (like your `serverResponse`) to the constructor of one of my classes (like `Person`) and I save it as an instance variable. And then I create accessor methods on the prototype like so:

```
function Person(serverResponse) {
    this.serverResponse = serverResponse;
}

Person.prototype.getFoo = function() {
   return this.serverResponse.foo;
};

Person.prototype.getId = function() {
   return this.serverResponse.id;
};

...
```